# Ntp on secondary/redundanct system does not sync time from primary

Tags: linux, time, synchronization, ntp

I have two systems One acts as Primary/Active and has Internet connection and gets time from NTP server. The second system is Secondary/Passive and has no connection to the external world.

Primary and Secondary are connected on a private network interface eth1.
Primary   has IP 169.254.10.10 Subnet: 255.255.255.248 Broadcast: 169.254.10.15 
Secondary has IP 169.254.10.11 Subnet: 255.255.255.248 Broadcast: 169.254.10.15

Primary has the following ntp.conf Configuration

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
server 91.189.94.4   
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
restrict 169.254.10.0 mask 255.255.255.248
broadcast 169.254.10.15
disable auth
broadcastclient
```

I sync time on Secondary with only ntpdate and do not run ntpd daemon on Secondary.
on Secondary i run  ntpdate -b -t 4 -p 4 -u 169.254.10.10 (Primary Interface IP)
And Ntpd server is running on Primary with the above said Configuration.

The time on Secondary is not updated and throws error 
ntpdate[3636]: no server suitable for synchronization found

Thanks
Visu

Comment: Doublecheck your netmask, 169.254.10.0/255.255.255.248 won't cover 169.254.10.10

Comment: I changed the subnet to 255.255.255.0 and the broadcast accordingly. But i see the same error.